# Is there a way to capture WAF policy changes at the GUI level and then use that to trigger azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-waf

I am working to deploy an Azure WAF policy from Azure Repo. I have configured my AzureDevops pipeline that upon commit of a changes to WAF policy or its parameters file it will deploy the new waf policy to a specified environment. This was pretty easy. However I am stumped on how to capture if a change is made to the WAF Policy at the GUI level and then export the newly changed WAF to source control to kick off my pipeline that way.

I am sure the PowerShell won't be too difficult to take WAF policy from a resource group and send it to a repo as a json file. But the capturing of the event part is completely stumping me. I have looked in to  Azure function triggers, but this doesn't seem to be what I am looking for (I could very well be wrong as I am a new Azure user here). Any ideas to point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your WAF.

Click on the alerts.
[image]

You can add the necessary conditions  :

[image]

The changes will be usually tracked at the All Administrative operations.